# How to implement the right initializer list of the queue linked list

Tags: c++

Is this part of the code written right? If no could someone help with the right initializer list implementation?

```
    queue(std::initializer_list<int> ilist): queue() {
    
    for(size_t val : ilist){
    
        if(front != back->next){
        push(val);
        }
    }   

}
```

The private part of queue looks like this:

```
    class queue {

// Private type for internal queue use only
struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;
    // node constructor
    node(int x): value(x), next(nullptr) { }
};

// Fields of the queue object

size_t queue_size;

node* front;
node* back;
```

Comment: The `int` to `size_t` conversion can bring troubles.

Comment: How look `queue()`? (how `front`/`back` initialized?). Which is the purpose of `if (front != back->next)`?

Comment: `queue` should be extended to be constructible from iterators. The init-list constructor would then be: `queue(std::initializer_list<int> ilist) : queue(ilist.begin(), ilist.end()) {}`

Comment: It certainly doesn't *look* right - the conditional makes it look odd, and the iteration over `size_t` looks like you have a rewritten indexing loop.

Comment: Without a specification, it's *difficult* to judge "right".